# Can shell run a specific comand after 'command not found'

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I want to execute a pre-set command automatically after I run some command witch can not be found. Is there any solution?

Let me clear my question. Set a command, and this command will be executed automatically when I type some command in the shell and get "command not found" result.

Comment: Run command _only_ if 'command not found'?

Comment: You should use `which yourCommand` and check the exit status `$?` and put conditional statement. If you are doing it inside some script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With zsh, use the function *command_not_found_handler*:

```
command_not_found_handler () {
  echo Oups
}
```

With bash, use the function *command_not_found_handle*:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
  echo Oups
}
```

Using this mechanism, there is a tool for Archlinux that gives you the package that contains your missing command. This tool is called *command_not_found* and is available on AUR and on [Github](https://github.com/metti/command-not-found). Similar applications exist for other distributions.

Comment: This might be what I want, I will try it later.

Comment: it works. However, the command in 'command_not_found_handler' is executed in subshell, it has no effects on the current shell.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you can chain commands to execute only if previous was successful using the logical `and` operator:

```
command1 && command2
```

you can use the logical `or` operator to have `command2` run only if `command1` failed:

```
command1 || command2
```

This will, however, capture all error states from `command1`, not just the `not found` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command to achieve your goal,

```
cmd1 2>&1 | grep "command not found" > /dev/null && cmd2
```

Brief explanation,

1. `cmd1`: is the command may no be found in your system
2. `cmd2`: if error message for `cmd1` is "command not found", execute `cmd2`